# PlayerDropItemEvent does wrong things

Tags: bukkit

Today I wanted to cancel the PlayerDropItemEvent but if I go into my Inventory and do 'Option + Q'  the itemstack dissapears

Src Code:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onDrop(PlayerDropItemEvent event) {
    event.setCancelled(true);
}
```

but if I do it like that the above mentioned problem happens.
The console doesn't show something either

Comment: Did you implement Listener and register events? You can test if the event is called by printing something in the console. Use `System.out.println("...");`

Comment: @KrijnToet It detects the drop event and it gets triggered. Looks like this problem only occurs in Creative Mode

Comment: It appears to be working for me just fine. Assuming 'Option + Q' is your control to drop a full stack? It's still working fine. The only way I was able to reproduce your problem is in creative mode when you open the inventory, hover over an item and then drop the item, the item disappears. Is this the problem you mean?

Comment: @KrijnToet yes I mean dropping a full stack in creative mode

Comment: What version of Spigot are you using?

Comment: @Lucan I am using Version 1.8.8

Comment: And just to be sure, the problem is that even though the event is cancelled, players in creative can still drop items?

Comment: Minecraft players have his inventory on memory, maybe it's not disappearing, just getting bug. You have tried to see what happens if you leave the server and join again?

Comment: What about `Player#updateInventory()`?

Comment: If I rejoin the disappeared itemw duplicate themselves

Comment: @Lucan the problem is that items will bug disappear if you drop a whole stack in Creative Mode

Answer (score 0):

If you cancel an inventory-bound event, it could be possible that the player's inventory doesn't get updated. Use

```java
new BukkitRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        p.updateInventory();
    }
}.runTask(plugin);
```

(delay because you can't do 2 inventory bound actions in 1 tick).

PS: Get an instance of your plugin by using `MyMain.getPlugin(MyMain.class)`.